Imagemajick "Convert" command fails to process files with an apostrophe in the name
I'm having a lot of success with the "convert" command (Imagemagick) using:
for i in *.{jpg,JPG}; do convert $i -quality 25% ~/Pictures/NEW/${i}; done;

Only, when it tries to process files which contain an apostrophe ('),
e.g: Italy '17 555.JPG, Italy '17 561.JPG, Italy '17 565.JPG
I get errors:
convert convert: Unable to open file (Italy) [No such file or directory].
convert convert: Unable to open file (Italy) [No such file or directory].
convert convert: Unable to open file (Italy) [No such file or directory].
etc...

Should I be putting some sort of escape characters in the code ?
I had to rename them with the multiple file rename tool which took a few minutes.

Does this answer your question? Passing command line argument from the terminal with apostrophe or quote

The apostrophes are in the file names not part of the command arguments.

Quote: for i in *.{jpg,JPG}; do convert "$i" -quality 25% "~/Pictures/NEW/${i}"; done;

Thanks Goose. Your fix sort of worked except it kept the processed files in the same folder and renamed them like: 555.JPG, 561.JPG, 565.JPG. But you gave me an idea. Instead of quoting the whole Destination Directory, I just quoted the destination i-Variable at the end, so I ended up with: for i in *.{jpg,JPG}; do convert "$i" -quality 25% ~/Pictures/NEW/"${i}"; done;
AND IT WORKED !!!!  So thanks for your valuable contribution. SOLVED

You're probably better off renaming them first - apostrophes in file names are nasty. Simulate: rename -n "s/'//g" *.jpg Change -n to -v to act

Totally agree. The 'Search and Replace'  option in Thunar's Rename tool is really good but it's nice to learn these coding skills. They may one day come in handy again. I don't have voting rights yet but I would have voted you up for that assist.

Yes but more powerful at the command line as above. If you get it wrong in Thunar, you might find yourself sorting out a big mess and possibly applying a restore from backup. The above will tell you what is going to happen
